# A smooth function describing a unbounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $D$ be a unbounded domain  defined by
\begin{equation}
D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid |xy|<1\}.
\end{equation}
Can we find $C^2$ function $\Phi\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties?

- $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \Phi(x,y)>0\}$.
- $\partial D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \Phi(x,y)=0\}$.
- $|\nabla \Phi| (x,y) \ge 1$ for every $(x,y)\in \partial D$.
- All derivatives  of $\Phi$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The third and fourth conditions are slightly restrictive.

Comment: Have you tried something like $(x,y)\mapsto(1-x^2y^2)/(1+x^2y^2)$?

Comment: @Boxonix  Thank you for your comment.  I have not tried it. I will try it soon.